# What is the angular way of hiding all specific divs with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to do a simple thing:

I have an app, which has certain divs that in need to show (Only the specific one) and hide if clicked somewhere outside of it (All with the specific class for example).

This is easy using jquery:

```
$('some-class').style('display','none') //psuedo code here
```

How should i do the same with angular js?

A specific reason to do so:

I want to build a simple select drop-down (I don't want to use one that exist, i want to understand this...), when i click one, it suppose to open a div right beneath the button, when i click outside of it, it suppose to close not only this one, but some other elements like it in the app.

one point worth mentioning: Not all my select boxes are pre-rendered, some are dynamically added (inside directive), so not all of the are in the $scope, but inside them directives which has isolated scope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its better to make directives for these kind of things:

Make a directive for toggleDisplay as following

```
app.directive('toggleDisplay', function() {
  return function(scope, element) {
    element.bind('click', function() {
     element.toggleClass('unneeded-class'); // or something else
    });
  };
});
```

and then you can apply this directive to any element in the html:

```
<div toggle-display></div>
```

You can make a drop down logic or kindof accordion etc following this pattern

> How do i listen to a click anywhere in the app, that when i click it
>   and "that" element is not the select box, close all the select boxes?

let suppose you have that opend/dispalyed div that you want to hide when you click outside of it . give it a class "divvy" and attach the following directive to its wrapping container:

```
 app.directive('toggleFocus', function() {
      return function(scope, element) {
        element.bind('click', function() {
         if(!element.hasClass('divvy'))
         angular.element(document.querySelector('.divvy')).css({display:'none'}) 
        });
      };
    });
```

html:

```
<div toggle-focus>
   <div class="divvy"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you toggle the class on the `body` - then you can get a lot out of it as well, over the page as a whole. : )

Comment: it depends whats the complete logic and scenario but UI things are best to be manipulated with directives :)

Comment: How do i listen to a click anywhere in the app, that when i click it and "that" element is not the select box, close all the select boxes?

Comment: @totothegreat select boxes can not be opened and closed that way. what do you mean by closing select boxes please elaborate

Comment: What i meant, a div underneath a certain button is opened (ng-show that div), i want, when i click outside of it, to close it down (ng-hide on that "opened" div(ng-hide on it)), what if i have more than one "select boxes" like this in my body?

Comment: Seems good, let's see what other people come up with, if no one will answer for the next hour, it's the one for me :)

Answer (score 1):

It's in the angular documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

```
<!-- when $scope.myValue is truthy (element is visible) -->
<div ng-show="myValue"></div>

<!-- when $scope.myValue is falsy (element is hidden) -->
<div ng-show="myValue" class="ng-hide"></div>
```

just attach ng-show="whateverValue" to each div you want to hide/show based on whether "whateverValue" is true/false

Comment: This will hide things, but as the OP mentioned... their situation is more complicated. What if this affected 100 elements or something?

Comment: Sorry, when i answered this the only question @totothegreat had written was "$('some-class').style('display','none') //psuedo code here
How should i do the same with angular js?"