# How to hide all the divs of same class except first class in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to hide all div having same class except first one.Here I have a select,and a div whose data will come on change of select.when we onchage,critical and major will come.Here I need to hide all heading  of 'critical' except first one,similarly I need to hide all heading(h4)  of 'major' except first one,if its more than one.Here these value/id or class may change based on json. I need to do in angularjs.can anyone please help me.Here is the code.
https://plnkr.co/edit/77PXskAuwtG0uAVsK1fz?p=preview

### HTML

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="change" ng-model="x" ng-change="update()">
    <option value="condition">condition</option>
    </select>
    <div class="main">
<div  ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{emp[attr]}}">
<h4 class="{{emp[attr]}}">{{emp[attr]}}</h4>
<p class="values">{{emp[attr]}}</p>
</div>
</div>
```

### SCRIPT

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.groups = [
    {
      name: 'Malaria',
      symptom:'fever',
      categoty:'critical',
      id:'1'
    },

    {
      name: 'cancer',
      symptom:'diesease',
      categoty:'critical',
      id:'3'
    },
    {
      name: 'fever',
      symptom:'diesease',
      categoty:'critical',
      id:'3'
    },
    {
     name: 'Cold',
      symptom:'colds',
      categoty:'major',
      id:'2'
    }
    ]
  $scope.update = function() { 

   if($scope.x == 'condition'){
   $scope.id='categoty';
    $scope.attr = 'categoty';
   }

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all instances of the class except the first using the Level3 selectors

div.class:not(:first-child)

https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/

Marry this with a plain js function or a directive as explained in the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27639866/1020735

Comment: Thanks for your help,here class name  is coming dynamically here from json,how to handle here

Comment: Check if you can use construct the condition and eval it. I am unable to test it right now

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want unique objects in the array - based on the field `categoty` (should be "category" btw.). The field yielded should always be the first.

So, this should work:

```
  var groups = [{
    name: 'Malaria',
    symptom: 'fever',
    categoty: 'critical',
    id: '1'
  }, {
    name: 'cancer',
    symptom: 'diesease',
    categoty: 'critical',
    id: '3'
  }, {
    name: 'fever',
    symptom: 'diesease',
    categoty: 'critical',
    id: '3'
  }, {
    name: 'Cold',
    symptom: 'colds',
    categoty: 'major',
    id: '2'
  }]

  var existing = {};
  $scope.groups = groups.filter(function(entry) {
    if (existing[entry.categoty]) {
      return false;
    }
    existing[entry.categoty] = true;
    return true;
  });
```

Comment: Here critical value is coming only once,it should not restrict,it should come as per json, only heading should be restrict.

Answer (score 0):

Add a secondary class to all div elements to be affected, such as for standardization of style, and use that class to affect visibility.

```
<div class="status" ng-repeat="emp in groups" ng-attr-id="{{emp[attr]}}">
</div>

div.status:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: it showing error unspected token :,again if I use it it will hide major also,here I need to hide based on value.if critical is coming multiple times it should comes once again if major is coming multiple times it should display once.If in future I add 3 minor in category again minor should comes only once.

Comment: Use JavaScript to count how many of your major and minor class divs there are. If count > 1, then use AngularJS to add a secondary class to those unnecessary divs.